# Apache worker mpm changes having no impact

Tags: apache-2.2, mpm-worker

I am trying to load test my apache server with jmeter (10 hosts, 10 threads) with various mpm config. I tried various settings from maxclient 150 to 3000, but there is negligible difference in the average response time.

The cpu usage reaches around 10% and the ram usage is much less around 100 mb or so in total. The box on which apache server runs is a dual core,16 GB box.

Any idea why the mpm config changes are not having any affect on the response time ?

edit : It is a standard apache which server which serves static content like images, js files, css files etc

Regarding 10 threads : I am really really sorry, I didn't explained the threads part fully. I did tried different values of thread from 6 to 30. for both the configs the degrade was similiar. For 150 maxclient settings it changed from ~45ms to ~430ms, for the 3000 maxclient settings it changed from ~45ms to ~420ms. I am not sure where I am making the mistake.

Comment: what type of applications are you testing?

Comment: 10x10=100 < 150 :)

Answer (score 1):

As GioMac pointed out, your math is flawed.

Apache `MaxClients` limits only have an effect if you *hit the limit*.
10 hosts with 10 threads each is 100 clients.
If `MaxClients` is set to 150 you will never turn away a client with those settings.

Either add more jmeter clients (another 10 hosts, or increase to 20 threads/host), or reduce `MaxClients` to a value below 100 so that you hit the limit. There should then be an observable difference in performance.